# Building i386 (32-bit) apps on x86_64 (64-bit) Mountain Lion

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, osx-mountain-lion

I am building on a Mac OS X 10.8.2 workstation running GCC 4.7.2 obtained via MacPorts. I can build 64-bit (`x86_64`) apps with this setup.

I am trying to build a 32-bit binary from source by adding the `-arch i386` to the compilation flags. I'd like to add support for 32-bit clients on 10.5 and 10.6.

I get the following error messages (among others) which seem relevant to the lack of 32-bit libraries:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/lib/gcc47/libgcc_ext.10.5.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file /opt/local/lib/gcc47/libgcc_ext.10.5.dylib (1 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/lib/gcc47/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12/4.7.2/libgcc.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /opt/local/lib/gcc47/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12/4.7.2/libgcc.a
```

My questions are:

- Is there a different flag I should use for this, instead of `-arch i386`?
- Or, where can I obtain (or how can I compile) the `i386` libraries I need to install, to get 32-bit support?

(Can I compile `i386` architecture libraries from downloading GCC 4.7.2 source? Is there a specific set of options I should add to the `./configure` statement to enable this?)

- Once these libraries are installed, how does my current gcc installation "know" where these libraries will be found?
- Is there anything I can add via Xcode 4.5.2? I am already doing this on the command-line, but I can only see "command-line tools" and iOS simulators as download options in the Preferences applet.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23227562/1959808

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuilding the MacPorts installation of GCC 4.7.2 with the `+universal` option provided support for compiling both 32- (`i386`) and 64-bit (`x86_64`) binaries.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the MacPorts install of GCC and install the "command-line tools" package through XCode. Once you've done this, `gcc -arch i386` will work as expected.

Comment: It turns out Clang/LLVM's C++ support is not complete, so my codebase breaks if I try to use those tools. It looks like Xcode is out. Is there a way to bootstrap GCC 4.7.2 to add `i386` support?